# How to make the sum of range to output at the top not the bottom?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am adding values in many ranges, each range defined by a certain ID number. I need to know the total merchandise purchase for each registrant at an event together with the merchandise purchases for their guests.  If ID numbers are in column A, Registrant and Guest names are in Column B, merch purchases for each person in Column C, and combined merch purchases for registrant and their guests needs to go into Column D.

I am using the following formula in Cell D2:

```
=IF(A2<>A3, SUMIF(A:A,A2,C:C), " ")
```

The formula works great except for one thing. The ranges go in this order and cannot be changed:

```
Registrant
Guest
Registrant 
Guest
Guest
Registrant
Guest
```

and so on.
Every time the word registrant occurs this is the start of a new range, so the sum in that range is occuring at the bottom of a range in a guest row.  I need it to appear at the top in the registrant's row.

Any idea how I can make the formula output at the top of the range instead of the bottom?

Comment: share some sample data, and an example of what the outcome sould look like

Answer (score 0):

Rethink your premise. You don't want a "sum at the top", do you? That doesn't really sound like something Excel can do. You want a sum to show up in only one row for a given subset of data. Which row? The first one. How do you test for "first"?

Creative use of a locked range.

[image]

`=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A2)=1,SUMIF(A:A,A2,C:C),"")`

If your A is the first A (that is, the count of that A from the start of the sheet to that row is 1), then do the sum. Your `SUMIF` needed no modification - just the condition in which to print it on the row.